# Can we add other password service like password hash as backup for ADFS?

Tags: azure, entra-id, adfs, azureadconnect

I have configured ADFS password authentication. Now I have question if ADFS goes down for any reason, how do I cope with this situation? What steps do I need to add other password authentication service as backup for ADFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't, ADFS is now your source of truth for authentication. You need to build your ADFS infrastructure to be resilient to down time.

Comment: you mean to say, either I have to Build ADFS server with high redundancy or else I have to manually change the sign in method from AD Connect to Password Hash in case Organization facing big network disaster at least remote user can able to get access of resources......right?

Comment: Correct. When you made the choice to use ADFS you added a reliance on your infrastructure to your auth process. It’s now up to you to make that reliable.

Comment: thank you very much.....